# Google sheets Query function convert string to date

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Here is the link to the sample data and query function. Currently it returns the date as string as the raw data has string. How can I convert it to date?

My current query looks like this : `query(A2:C, "select A, sum(B) , sum(C) where A is NOT NULL group by A label sum(B) '' , sum(C) ''",0)`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13o8ZaOJmrpgNmbTCU98yzhFpv_ALfil4RGwg9v5QlIw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locale for the Sheet is 'United States' but the entered date-type values are typically European (dd/mm/yyyy), therefore try:

```
=arrayformula(query({datevalue(regexreplace(to_text(A2:A),"(.|..)[\/\-\.](.|..)[\/\-\.](.*)","$2\/$1\/$3")),B2:C}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) , sum(Col3) where Col1 is NOT NULL group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' , sum(Col3) ''",0))
```

[image]